# How to use Jacobi determinant in this simple transformation?

Tags: integration

I have two variables:$\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$, then I introduce $\vec{\xi}_1 = \vec{x}_1+\vec{x}_2$ and $\vec{\xi}_2 = \vec{x}_1-\vec{x}_2$.

How does the volume element: $\int d^3 \vec{x}_1 d^3 \vec{x}_2$ related to $\int d^3 \vec{\xi}_1 d^3 \vec{\xi}_2$?

Vectors are in three dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A strong hint in the right direction. By using change of variables,
$$\int \mathrm{d}\vec\xi_1\mathrm{d}\vec\xi_2 = \int \left|D_{\vec x_1,\vec x_2}~\vec f(\vec x_1, \vec x_2)\right|~\mathrm{d}\vec x_1\mathrm{d}\vec x_2$$
where $D_{x_1, x_2}$ is the Jacobian, $|\cdot|$ is the determinant of a matrix and $$\vec f(\vec x_1, \vec x_2) = (\vec \xi_1, \vec \xi_2) = (\vec x_1 + \vec x_2, \vec x_1, -\vec x_2)$$

Comment: This is a $6\times6$ matrix, and its determinant is $2^6$, right?